# File reading offset in case of application restart

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee

Question is more on designing part than coding.

I have one huge File containing Mobile numbers, So what we do is read 50 numbers in one go and update the offset in database table `startOffset=0` and `endOffset=50`. 
Now, start sending SMS to numbers one by one and once done, 
another 50 numbers are picked from file and update Offset as `startOffset=51` and `endOffset=100`, now start sending SMS, say I have sent sms till 66 offset, PROBLEM comes when power goes off or application restart suddenly due to many reasons.

Now when application restarts, I will not come to know on what offset I have to start again (ie 67 in our case.). I will come to know that I lost in 51 to 100 chunk, So what I can do is start sending sms again from 51 but this is wrong as sms will be sent twice to number which we already sent.

Also, I can do like after sending each sms, update the `currentPointer` to DB, but this will make the system slow.

Can someone please suggest the best way to do this.

Comment: Why not just use a database engine?

Comment: I hope you're not making any kind of SMS spam engine. But the solution can be simple: write in a second file which numbers you already sent to. On restart, count the number of lines in that file. Or compare the contents (that would be good if there is a chance that the original file was changed in the meantime) The good thing about doing it this way is that if something really went wrong, you can go in by hand and see what actually happened (you have the numbers that was already sent to)

Comment: I can do that, in fact doing the same currently, but only problem is we need performance with accuracy and File operation make it bit slow.

Comment: @fge it is again a database operation right, which will take time.

Comment: Database engines are _made_ for that kind of stuff; what is more, using a separate engine will allow you to make your sending status independent of the status of your application. Nothing to lose!

Comment: I browsed on database engine and got to know that InnoDB, MyISAM etc. So according to you should be used? But what I am not getting is still a database operation which requires opening connection, execute query, close connection, which takes time right. Please guide me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that no number gets processed twice on restart, then you need to write to persistent storage for each number that gets processed, whether that be database or file. If the write operation is performing too slow for your requirements, find a faster way to persist it, e.g. another table, file or a different database system.

Answer (score 0):

Run sending messages and reading from Db as two different threads to increase performance. Also you need to use persistent storage for each number thats getting processed.